# Internet of things is what exactly?

Tags: mobile, internet, terminology

I have found that the term IOT (internet of things) is pretty vague. I am wondering if a mobile device, a cell phone, is this considered a part of the IOT realm?

It is a thing, and its connected to the internet.

Comment: Nay, a cell phone is supposed to be **your** means of communicating with the wide world. In the IoT, your toaster tells the world you've had two toasts for breakfast, your fridge counts the number of eggs you've scrambled, and your microwave conspires with your car to kill you.

Comment: [Internet of S***](https://twitter.com/internetofshit).

Comment: @AndréBorie - Yes, it's serious enough that iOS needs to be taken away from Apple and IoS repurposed for its true definition as I don't think the situation will go away any time soon. Profits and human nature get in the way. Also, AI will be good for humankind if Tay is any indicator. The earth will finally know peace when AI reaches the ultimate "Final Solution".

Answer (score 3):

The Internet of Things **is** a pretty vague definition which covers an emerging collection of items that can be assigned an IP address and connected to the internet.

Typically, up to this point, the Internet has consisted of servers, routers to interconnect everything and endpoints such as computers, mobile devices, remote SCADA devices and other business related things you might want interconnected, etc.

The IoT just expands that to refrigerators, remote controlled beer kegs, flashing light displays, cameras and any old thing that you decide to concoct that you want remote access and/or control including your local nuclear plant.

The big issue is that things like remote WiFi connected Barbie Dolls have a certain price level that they can be produced at, and so as is often the case, all attention to security is thrown out the window as an excessive added cost. Something I might add, that you don't want happening when you've included internet connected industrial process control into the IoT.

Comment: it seems like the distinction between IOT and ... "non IOT" devices is the complexity of the device. Is it a computer, or IOT.  That to me seems a bit complicated when you consider people using rasberry pi's, which I would consider a computer, to give things access to the internet. Maybe im just way off though.

Comment: Well, therein lies the issue. What are you doing with the Raspberry Pi, BeagleBone, Arduino or any other number of internet connected microprocessor systems? It ranges from highly complex industrial grade with security to bone dead simple. And so the whole thing is quite nebulous as a definition at this point. Is a internet controllable power strip an IoT device based on whether it's an http server controlled, password protected microprocessor device or a mini-computer controlled device that can use SSH/HTTPS and accepts certificates for authentication, authentication, audited access control?

Comment: A recent example: https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/719736 Fisher-Price Smart Toy platform allows some unauthenticated web API commands (CVE-2015-8269)